# How to calculate a random number in Go?

Tags: go

```
package main

import "fmt"

import "math/rand"

func main() {

    var milesdriven float64
    var enginerunningloud bool = true
    var changeoil bool = true

    if milesdriven >= 3000.0 || enginerunningloud == false {

        float64 := (milesdriven * Rand)
        changeoil = true
        fmt.Println("Change that oil duuuuuude")

    }

}
```

This is what I have so far but I keep getting imported and not used "math/rand" and also a undefined Rand what does that mean? And what should I do?

Comment: Did you even look at the preview before posting your question?

Comment: What's not to understand about the question though?

Answer (score 2):

See the [`math/rand` package documentation](http://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/) for how to generate random numbers.  e.g.:

```
package main

import "math/rand"
import "time"

func main() {
  seed := time.Now().UnixNano()
  random := rand.New(rand.NewSource(seed))
  println(random.Float64()) // => +8.277637e-001
  println(random.Int())     // => 7112143871403206581
  // etc.
}
```